# Getting lock status on npy file being saved

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I am writing a multi threaded program to compute matrices in parallel. In other words, each thread independently computes a large matrix and then appends it to the array loaded from a saved file. Finally, the appended variable is saved back onto the disk (using `np.save`). However, the problem occurs when two threads write/access the file simultaneously. My question is, is there a lock that is set when the file is being written to by one thread, so that the other threads can wait for the lock to be released to write/access the file?

An MWE is presented below

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def main():
    p = Pool(processes=8)
    files = os.listdir("matrices/dummy")
    for f in files:
        try:
            os.remove(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found while deleting")
    a = np.random.randn(1, 10, 10)
    np.save("matrices/dummy/saved_mat.npy", a)
    p.starmap(save_mat, enumerate(np.random.rand(8)))


def save_mat(index, sleep_dur):
    # time.sleep(sleep_dur)
    np.random.seed(index)
    try:
        a = np.load("matrices/dummy/saved_mat.npy")
        new_val = np.random.randn(1, 10, 10)
        a = np.concatenate([a, new_val], axis=0)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        a = np.random.randn(1, 10, 10)
    np.save("matrices/dummy/saved_mat.npy", a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    b = np.load("matrices/dummy/saved_mat.npy")
    c = 0
```

Most of the times, the program runs with no issues. But there are scenarios where an error is thrown, that reads

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,10,10).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.